# How do I calculate this integral along a complex line (not a contour) in mathematica?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, complex

Given the function:

$$f(z) = \frac{\pi ^2 \cot(\pi \sqrt z) \cot(\pi \sqrt {z-a})}{4\sqrt{z^2 - az}}$$

Where a is a positive constant and:

$$z = \frac{i}{b} + t $$
$$t>a$$

Where b is also a positive constant. Along the real line it has an infinite number of discontinuities. However when evaluated slightly offset into the positive complex quadrant I believe there are none. I simply don't know how to get *Mathematica* to evaluate the following integral:

$$\int_{\frac{i}{b} +a}^{\frac{i}{b} +2a} \frac{\pi ^2 \cot(\pi \sqrt z) \cot(\pi \sqrt {z-a})}{4\sqrt{z^2 - az}} dz $$

Does the integral even exist? Is it inappropriate that I am not integrating over a closed curve?

As requested here is what I've tried so far:

```
a ∈ Reals
b ∈ Reals
t ∈ Reals
z = I/b + t
f1 = ((π Sqrt[z] Cot[π Sqrt[z]])*(π Sqrt[-a + z]Cot[π Sqrt[-a + z]]))/(4 Sqrt[ z (-a + z)])
Integrate[f1, {t, a + 1, 2 a}]
```

Comment: Sub your `z` expression and integrate over `{t,a, 2a }` ?  In any case show the mathematica code you have tried.

Comment: your `Element` statements have no affect, you need to do this: `$Assumptions = {a \[Element] Reals, b \[Element] Reals, 
  t \[Element] Reals}` .  ( It doesn't help in this case however ).  I'm guessing there is no analytic solution.

Comment: Well that would be a bummer. What if I am just interested in the real part?

Comment: From the looks of your integral... this used to be a sum that was converted into a contour integral, wasn't it?

Comment: You are correct kind of. It results from multiplying the infinite sum of quadratic poles sum(1/(t-n^2)) and another which is shifted by the constant a. I then threw out the terms I didn't care about, leaving only a single cross term.

Comment: Why not use `NSum[]` instead?